# Eigenvalue of geometric series of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a matrix $T$ and its spectral radius $\rho(T)$ is less than one, i.e., $\rho(T) < 1$. Then, the geometric series of $T$ is represented as follows:
$$
\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} T^{j}=(I - T)^{-1}
$$

Let $\lambda_{i}$ be the i-th eigenvalue of the matrix $T$. My claim is that the eigenvalue of $(I-T)^{-1}$ related to $\lambda_{i}$ is $\frac{1}{1-\lambda_{i}}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$ where $n$ is the dimension of the matrix $T$. Is it true?

Proof:
Suppose $T=S\Lambda S^{-1}$ where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues. Then, a matrix series on $T$ is written as
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}T^{j}=S(I+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\Lambda^{j})S^{-1}
$$
Let's pick $i$-th diagonal entry of $I+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\Lambda^{j}$. Then, the entry is represented as follows:
$$
1 + \lambda_{i} + \lambda_{i}^{2} + \lambda_{i}^{3} + \cdots + \lambda_{i}^{k-1}=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\lambda_{i}^{j}
$$
Since $\rho(T) < 1$, all eigenvalues of $T$ are less than one. Hence, the series of the eigenvalue $\lambda_{i}$ converges to
$$
\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\lambda_{i}^{j} = \frac{1}{1-\lambda_{i}} 
$$

One more question: 
Let $\tilde{\Lambda}$ be a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entry is $\frac{1}{1-\lambda_{i}}$. From the above proof, $T=S\Lambda S^{-1}$ and $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}T^{j}=S\tilde{\Lambda}S^{-1} = (I-T)^{-1}$. Are there any relationship between eigenvectors of $T$ and those of $(I-T)^{-1}$?

Comment: In the term $I + \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\Lambda^{j}$, $I$ should be removed.

Comment: $T$ is not always diagonalizable. Thus, it is not okay to use a diagonal $\Lambda$.

Comment: Use the argument shown here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ \lambda \ne 1$ and $Tx= \lambda x$. Then $(I-T)x=(1- \lambda)x,$ thus

$\frac{1}{1- \lambda}(I-T)x=x$, Therfore

$$(I-T)^{-1}x=\frac{1}{1- \lambda}x$$